# While installing Ubuntu: black cloud builds up at mid screen; and 0.0 B disk space message

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive

I have been trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS 64-bit from a CD. I have American Mega Trends motherboard, with AMD Athlon 450 processor 3.20 GHZ. I am getting "CMOS CheckSum Bad", then I press F1 to load default values.
As I go thru the installation stages, I get the following problems:

1- at each stage at first the screen is normal, then after a few seconds a sort of small black cloud (3"x4")  builds up in the middle of the screen with some fragmented lines. but I am still able to click and go thru the next stage.

2- at the 4th stage it says "you need at least 8.6 GB disk space, the computer has only 0.0 B"

I have installed a brand new Samsung 500 GB SSD, and I un-plugged and re-plugged the hard drive few times to make sure the connections are right. I tried to install Windows 7 before, but currently I do not have any OS on the drive yet. I like to run just the Ubuntu with no partition.
Also I like to re-format the drive to get rid of any residue from previous installations, but I guess that option comes toward the end of the installation.

I used a different CD just in case there was a problem with the CD. But the problem still remains. I have also tried "Try Ubuntu". It installs it, but when next time I reboot, I get into BIOS screen with options F2 Set Up, F6 Instant Flash, F11 Boot Menu. Basically back to square one.

Any comments/solutions appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing the BIOS battery on your motherboard.

Comment: One other thing, make sure that in the BIOS the drive is set for AHCI for installation.

Comment: I changed the motherboard battery. The problem still exists. I went to SATA Operation Mode, there were only two choices there: IDE and RAID. There was no option for AHCI. The AHCI should be under SATA Operation Mode or should I look elsewhere? Thanks

Comment: It should right under where you looked in your BIOS.  Hmmmm, maybe check with your MB manufacturer if they have a BIOS update to allow for AHCI mode.